# Why does the second 'delete :destroy' in this spec not run?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a spec that is giving unexpected results. I've not been able to track down the cause. Can anyone help point me in the right direction?

```
let(:object1) { create :object }
let(:object2) { create :object }
let(:user)    { create :user }
describe "DELETE #destroy" do
  before :each do
    Rails.logger.info "Object 1 ID: #{object1.id}"
    Rails.logger.info "Object 2 ID: #{object4.id}"
    user.roles.push Role.where(name: 'FullAccess').first
    sign_in user
    delete :destroy, {:id => object1.to_param}
  end
  it {
     expect {
       delete :destroy, {:id => object2.to_param}
     }.to change(Object, :count).by(-1)
  }
end
```

Results in

```
Failure/Error:
  expect {
    delete :destroy, {:id => object2.to_param}
  }.to change(Object, :count).by(-1)
expected #count to have changed by -1, but was changed by 0
```

But if I comment out `delete` in the before block, the test passes.

```
before :each do
  sign_in user
  # delete :destroy, {:id => office1.to_param}
end
```

Why would the second object not be deleted?

### edit

The method being tested is

```
def ObjectController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource
  def destroy
    Rails.logger.info "DELETE OBJECT ID: #{@object.id}" 
    @object.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to objects_url, notice: t('.notice') }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
end
```

### Edit 2

Added logging codes to the examples above. The log output now includes

```
Object 1 ID: 1
Object 2 ID: 2
DELETE OBJECT ID: 1 
DELETE OBJECT ID: 1
```

Comment: is it a typo, you have taken `office1` instaed of `object1`?

Comment: @Sravan a typo in the question, apologies

Comment: @AndyHarvey Where do you set `@object`, and does it have the correct value when the test runs?

Comment: via cancan's `load_and_authorize_resource`, though I will test setting this explicitly. hold on

Comment: interesting! the test passes if i define `@object = Object.find...`. It would appear that the @object defined by cancan's `load_and_authorize_resource` is not reloaded between `delete` actions in my test. any idea why this might be?

Comment: Are you stubbing anything that could cause this? Could you paste the code that populates the @object variable?

Comment: That's why I don't use controller specs. There's always something broken :)

Comment: @Codebeef I've updated the question with some details. Nothing being stubbed. Though the test does assign a role that has access. I've updated the action code as well, but nothing strange happening here either

Comment: So when running the spec, do you get `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` thrown, or is another object allocated to @object, and if so, what is the id value, and does it match the id being passed into the request? If there is something amiss with the @object being returned, it should be traceable.

Comment: this error was happening seemingly intermittently throughout my controller specs. after your suggestion, I now see that all the passing tests have a `before_action @object = `, whereas all the failing tests rely on `load_and_authorize_resource`. Something strange is happening in this helper

Comment: When the specs fail, is the object not being loaded, or is the wrong object being loaded?

Comment: Are you sure that `user` has permission to destroy the `@object`? I know you say that "Though the test does assign a role that has access", but can you double check this?

Comment: the role definitely has permission `manage :all`, and otherwise the test would fail when the line is commented.

Comment: I have added some logging code. see the question above. @object appears not to be reloaded between steps in the test. still unsure why

Comment: @Codebeef how would I check whether it is wrong object loaded, or not reloaded?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129352/discussion-between-codebeef-and-andy-harvey).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### 1. Lazy Evaluation

This is because your `object2` is created and immediately destroyed within the expect block. [`let` is lazy, `let!` is immediately evaluated](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-5/docs/helper-methods/let-and-let)

Change your `let` to `let!`, and it should work:

```
let!(:object1) { create :object }
let!(:object2) { create :object }
describe "DELETE #destroy" do
  before :each do
    sign_in user
    delete :destroy, {:id => object1.to_param}
  end
  it {
     expect {
       delete :destroy, {:id => object2.to_param}
     }.to change(Object, :count).by(-1)
  }
end
```

#### 2. Memoized object

As for the other part of the problem, the reason you're seeing the spec fail is because the controller in the before block is the same instance as in the test. The object is being set only if it's not already set, so it won't get reset on your second call to the delete method (with different params). Something like this is happening:

```
@object ||= Object.find(...)
```

Removing the delete call to the controller action under test in the before block should fix this.

Comment: How would you explain that if he comments out the first deletion, it somehow works?

Comment: Using `let!`, the test still fails with the same error.

Comment: @AndyHarvey: "it still fails with `let!`" - try restarting spring if you use it.

Comment: @AndyHarvey there is something else at play here. What does the method you're testing look like?

Comment: @Codebeef i will add the method to the question

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Sorry - didn't reply: "How would you explain that if he comments out the first deletion, it somehow works?" - I think there is more than one problem :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev happy to show more, but don't want to overload the page with irrelevant code. I think the relevant bits are there.

Comment: @AndyHarvey: yes, not blaming you or anything. Just observing that current info was not enough to identify the problem.